# Arabic-Indic digits appear in a form field instead of European digits

Tags: html, css, forms, web, arabic

I'm facing an issue in developing an Arabic-language website where in form fields, only Arabic digits (⁨٠⁩, ⁨١⁩, ⁨٢⁩, ⁨٣⁩…) appear.  I want to allow users to enter European digits (0, 1, 2, 3…) but I am cannot get it to work:

[image: screenshot]

Is there any way to fix this issue? How can I allow the user to input European digits?

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    font-family:'customfont';
    background-size: 120px 80px;
    /*font-family: Kufyan-Arabic-Black;
     src: url('font/KufyanArabic-Black.ttf');*/
}

/* font */
@font-face {
  font-family:'customfont' ;
  src: url(font/GE_SS_Unique_Light.otf);
}

body{
    background-image: url(image/duck.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #FEFAF1 ;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: fixed; /*center*/
    position: relative;
    direction: rtl;
  }

  .container{
    width:88%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-width: 10px;
  }

  .button {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 40px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: large;
    margin: 0 0px;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px#CCECBD;
    transition: 0.4s;
    color: black;
    background-color: #CCECBD;
  }

 .button:hover {
  box-shadow:lightblue;
}

.con {
    background: #F1F2F0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    width: 400px;
    padding: 30px 40px;
    position: absolute; /*fixed*/
    top: 53%;
    left: 53%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 9px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 2px #F1F2F0(230, 254, 164); 
    
    }
    .con h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    font-size: 24px;
    }
    .input {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    }
    .input label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .input input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .input small {
    position: absolute;
    top: 42px;
    right:120px;
    display: block;
    color: #e74c3c;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    visibility: hidden;
    }
    .input.success input {
    border: 2px solid #2ecc71;
    }
    .input.error input {
    border: 2px solid #e74c3c;
    }
    .input.error small {
    visibility: visible;
    }
    button {
    border: 0px; 
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 10px 0; 
    text-align: center;
    width: 40%; 
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-size: 18px; 
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer; 
    align-items: center;
    margin-right:140px;
    background: #C5E8B4;
    opacity: 0.9;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 12px rgba(73, 83, 64, 0.25);
    }
```

```html
<body dir="rtl">
<div>
  <div class="con">
    <h1> إنشاء حساب</h1>
    <form action="" id="form" class="form">

    <div class="input" style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center">
    <label for="P_FirstName">الاسم الاول</label>
    <input
    type="text"
    name="P_FirstName"
    id="P_FirstName"
    autocomplete="off"
    />
    <small>Error message</small>
    </div>
    <div class="input" style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center">
      <label for="P_LastName"  >الاسم الاخير</label>
      <input
      type="text"
      name="P_LastName"
      id="P_LastName"
      autocomplete="off"
      />
      <small>Error message</small>
      </div>

    <div class="input" style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center" lang="en" >
    <label for="P_Email" >البريد الالكتروني</label>
    <input
    type="text"
    name="P_Email"
    id="P_Email"
    placeholder="user@gmail.com"
    autocomplete="off"
    />
    <small>Error message</small>

    </div>

    <div class="input" lang="en" style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center">
      <label for="P_PhoneNum">رقم الهاتف </label>
      <input
      type="text"
      name="P_PhoneNum"
      id="P_PhoneNum"
      placeholder="05xxxxxxxx"
      autocomplete="off"
      />
      <small>Error message</small>
      </div>

    <div class="input" lang="en" style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center">
      <label for="ParentID" >اسم المستخدم </label>
      <input
      type="text"
      name="ParentID"
      id="ParentID"
      autocomplete="off"
      />
      <small>Error message</small>
      </div>

    <div class="input" lang="en" style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center">
    <label for="Password">كلمة المرور </label>
    <input
    type="password"
    name="Password"
    id="Password"
    placeholder="********"
    />
    <small>Error message</small>
    </div>
<button>إكمال</button>
         <br><br> 
    <label style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; margin-right: 130px; width: 200px;">لديك حساب بالفعل؟<a href="Sign_in.php">اضغط هنا</a></label>
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: In English we usually refer to 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 as "Arabic numerals" as opposed to I,III,III,IV..." which are "Roman numerals."   I expect that you mean that you want to allow entry of something else.  Maybe "Eastern-Arabic numerals." See https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Arabic_numerals-en.svg for possibilities.

Comment: I can't enter English number (1,2,3.,..), it only appear as Arabic digits (١،٢،٣،...) even though I added Lang="en" but it did't worked

Comment: so why right now in run code the numbers are not Arabic?

Comment: Have you switched to a keyboard layout with Arabic digits?

Comment: Have you looked into the developer console to check which Unicode code points are present in the field? (enter some digits, then look at `document.getElementById('P_Email').value.charCodeAt(...)`) Are they ASCII digits (range [U+0030, U+0039]) or Arabic digits ([U+0660, U+0669])? That should help you diagnose whether this is an issue with the display or with digit input.